# MySQL DATETIME format comparison - is strtotime needed?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, string-comparison

I've been doing something along the lines of..

```
$dt1 = '1000-01-01 00:00:00'; //really some val from db
$dt2 = '1000-01-01 00:00:10'; //another val maybe db maybe formatted

if(strtotime($dt1) > strtotime($dt2){
//do something
}
```

Is the strtotime needed? can i do a more direct comparison on the datetime formatted strings?

i.e.

```
if($dt1 > $dt2){
//do something
}
```

Will that always work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the [lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) of strings in the format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss` works as intended. You could even sort dates like that.

```
$dts = array(
  '1000-01-01 00:00:00',
  '2010-03-16 21:22:19',
  '1000-01-01 00:00:10',
  '1976-03-27 05:55:00', 
  '1976-03-27 05:54:00',
  '1968-08-21 12:00:00',
  '2001-01-01 00:00:01'
);

sort($dts);
foreach($dts as $dt) {
  echo $dt, "\n";
}
```

prints

```
1000-01-01 00:00:00
1000-01-01 00:00:10
1968-08-21 12:00:00
1976-03-27 05:54:00
1976-03-27 05:55:00
2001-01-01 00:00:01
2010-03-16 21:22:19
```

But keep in mind that you will get no feedback for strings that are *not* in the right format. So, if it *could be* that there are malformed strings you'd better check that, too. If that is not a concern, string1>string2 is ok.

edit: You could even let MySQL do the work. If this is better/equal/worse to doing it in php depends on what you're actually trying to achieve. E.g.

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", 'localonly', 'localonly'); 
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
// setting up a sample table with some values
$pdo->exec('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo (id int auto_increment, d datetime NOT NULL, primary key(id))');
$pdo->exec("INSERT INTO foo (d) VALUES ('1000-01-01 00:00:00'),('2010-03-16 21:22:19'),('1000-01-01 00:00:10'),('1976-03-27 05:55:00')");


$query = "
  SELECT
    d,
    (d>'1910-03-17 12:00:00') as flag
  FROM
    foo
";

foreach ( $pdo->query($query) as $row ) {
  echo $row['flag'] ? '+ ':'- ', $row['d'], "\n";
}
```

prints

```
- 1000-01-01 00:00:00
+ 2010-03-16 21:22:19
- 1000-01-01 00:00:10
+ 1976-03-27 05:55:00
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought that would work and use as arrays makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you have dates stored in string, using `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format, you can use the **alphabetical order** : it'll be the same as dates order.

Which means the comparisons on strings will have the same result as comparisons on dates.

I would add that there would be an advantage in not using [UNIX timestamps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) : those are limited to a range that goes from 1970 to 2038, as they are stored on 32 bits integers that represent a number of seconds since 1970-01-01 *(depending on your system, the range might be wider -- but not unlimited)*

Comment: The range/epoch of unix timestamps is a good point, esp. since the example consists of dates that are way out of the current epoch (might be a typo though =]).

Comment: just copied from the example datetime formate on the MySQL datetime page... def not using those dates!

Answer (score 0):

I usually use strtotime() to be safe in comparing dates as a timestamp value.

You can check by writing both IF statements and printing 'statement 1 true' in one and 'statement 2 true' in the other. Then try changing the values of dt1 and dt2 and see how that plays out.

Comment: This is what I was doing, but intuitively I didn't think it was necessary.